# Can a user be hurt by his own chakra?

Tags: naruto

In the Naruto world, is it possible to get hurt directly by your own chakra? For example, Naruto's Rasengan is a manifestation of his chakra, so is Sasuke's Chidori, and Itachi's Fire Style jutsu. If Naruto were to accidentally hit himself with his own Rasengan, would it affect him the same way it would if he used it on someone else? Because it's his own chakra, would his body just absorb it? Same goes for Sasuke's Chidori and Fire Style jutsu. If Itachi blew a fireball into the wind and it came back and hit him, would he be hurt by it?

Comment: Deidara puts chakra in his clay for it to explode. When he blew himself up, he died. Hence it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

In the Fourth Shinobi War, we discover that you can get hurt by your own chakra.

The best example is Naruto versus the Third Raikage.
[image]

Comment: Another example is the [Rasenshuriken](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasenshuriken). Before Naruto learns to throw it, Tsunade classifies it as a [Kinjutsu (Forbidden) Justu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kinjutsu) as it damages Naruto's arm on a cellular level. If he was immune to the justu, this would not be case

Answer (score 2):

To strike a finer point on this, one can be hurt by their own **moulded** or effectively weaponized chakra.  It isn't the case that we've seen unmoulded or non-weaponized chakra harm the originator.

It's important to note that chakra wasn't initially weaponized.  [Ninshu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ninsh%C5%AB), the precursor to ninjitsu, was originally meant to spread energies and thoughts between others, and to allow people to live in relative peace.

As an example, Naruto's [*Rasenshuriken*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasenshuriken) when used as a normal *Rasengan* actively damaged his body to the point that Tsunade wished it classified as a forbidden jutsu to prevent irreparable damage to him.

Another instance would be fully opening all Eight Gates.  In this context the chakra is being expelled from one's body to the degree that it is taking significant physical damage.  Might Guy opened all eight, and due to that fact (and the fact that normally one *would* die from that, but he was saved by Naruto), he's wheelchair bound and unable to be a ninja.  Lesser damage has been incurred by Rock Lee when he's opened up fewer gates, and has ended up in the hospital due to its side effects*.

<sup>The main effects of using the Eight Gates would *also* be damage to one's bones, but those are a direct result of taijutsu, and not necessarily the chakra.</sup>

Comment: Isn't the problem with the eighth gate that you can't close it again? Maybe I missed it but I thought you die from losing all your chakra.

Answer (score 2):

Any form of physical chakra can damage anyone, even the one who produced it. When Tsunade challenges Naruto to master the Rasengan in part 1, Naruto's hands are severely injured.... that's one of many examples of self chakra injury.

Also are we forgetting the fact that Itachi used his own crow Kotoamatsukami to place genjutsu on himself when he was in Edo Tensei? So not only physical but mental as well.